# Flashing folder with question mark appear when reboot macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I substituted a MacbookPro 13" HDD with a Corsair SSD and upgraded the RAM to 8GB.
I did a fresh install of OS X Mavericks but when the machine reboots (restarts), it shows a flashing folder with a question mark and doesn't detect the SSD. If I shut down the machine and switch it on then everything is OK, but on restart it can not detect the SSD and shows the flashing folder!

**just** on restart

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: In System Preferences, can you go to the "Startup Disk" preference, and check that the SSD is properly selected?

Comment: yes,SSD is selected in startup disk

Comment: The directory with the question mark means there is no valid boot disk found. There are 101 causes for an invalid bootdisk.

Comment: In order to answer your specific problem (related to the shutdown) please publish the console report around the time stamp in question. It appears that the suhtdown+restart is doing something incorrect.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Seems like no one below knows what you are asking and I am experiencing the same thing now.

Comment: OK, I have a Unibody 2009 17" Macbook Pro. After installing Yosemite I noticed it did not want to wake from sleep. I would either get the black screen with pointer or the folder with question mark. Here is what I have done to date...to NO avail. - Take to the Genius bar-they reinstalled the OS-no help - I performed clean installed the SSD-Nope - Then I read about updating the drives firmware-NADA - Then another clean install after ward. Still the same problem. I am using Time Machine to restore all my data FYI.
I simply don't put the machine to sleep or shut the lid....but I wish I could find

Comment: Its old question, but and progress? I have same problem with old MacBook White. After replacing old HDD with Corsair Force GS 240. Maybe Corsair problem?

Comment: I would first put back old RAM and try. When you try to detect the cause of the problem, you should get back to a working config and put new components one by one. When the problem reappears, there is your cause.

Comment: Did you check that the drive is compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible causes for your troubles as I see it with the information provided is that either the bless command for the SSD is corrupted or your NVRAM is corrupted.

Have you tried reseting the NVRAM/PRAM? This is done by holding down opt + cmd + p + r right after you power the Mac. Hold these four keys down until you hear the boot chime for the third time after which you can let go and your system will have cleared out what it boots to by default.

That is only the first portion of the fix because it will boot quicker now (or should) but you need to tell your system to boot to the SSD. Go into System Preferences and then Startup Disk as Kent suggest and highlight the SSD. At this point I even go far enough to tell Startup Disk to restart... This will test it immediately and you can let us now if that resolved the troubles you are having.

If not then you might have a damaged OS or some corrupted settings that are making your restarts unclean. I love a program called Onyx for clearing caches and Saved Application States. Try that out if issue remains and holler back if need be. http://www.titanium.free.fr/downloadonyx.php

Answer (score 1):

if you have taken all the backups you need from the previously used HDD you had in your Macbook Pro, put in your Macbook Pro's 'Mac OS X Install DVD' and wait for a couple of minutes.

It should directly lead you to your bootscreen and you should be able to install your software from the CD, since that is what is going to solve your problem. 'A lack of Software installed on your newly set up SSD' to say the least. Hope I could help :)

**PS: That is what I had and have done yesterday. Exactly the same things.**

Answer (score 1):

It's the "sleep" function that confuses my setup (early Macbook Pro Laptop, OS 10.6.8 running from a newly installed SSD). Thing goes to sleep and it can't wake up (beach ball). Upon restart, can't find System folder.

Solution being tested: Disable computer and disc "sleep" capability. Even display.

It's in a "burn-in" period now. Leaving it on, doing a lot of re-starts, only dimming display manually.